# Trying to set spark.sql.pivotMaxValues in AWS EMR Pyspark notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have similarity scores in a pyspark rdd in an EMR notebook. My columns are id_a, id_b, and my third column is similarity_score.

I want to cluster these IDs using kmeans. When I try to pivot this table to have IDs as rows and columns (where a cell is the similarity for two IDs) I get an error that I am exceeding the max columns in a pyspark rdd:

An error was encountered:
The pivot column id_b has more than 10000 distinct values, this could indicate an error. If this was intended, set spark.sql.pivotMaxValues to at least the number of distinct values of the pivot column.

This is the code to address this error in PySpark:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("MatrixReformat") \
    .config("spark.sql.pivotMaxValues", 20000) \ 
    .getOrCreate()
```

However, I can not change PySpark configurations within an EMR PySpark notebook.

Does anyone know how to set PySpark configurations within an AWS EMR cluster prior to launching a notebook workspace? Or alternatively, is there another way I can change the format of my table above to a pivot table without encountering this error?

Thanks!